# How do I save my current POST array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current `$_POST` output.

```
Array
(
    [fullname] => John Doe
    [email] => john@john.com
    [phone] => 123-455-6444
    [address] => 23-10 My Address
    [zip] => 12345

    [fullname_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => M. Owen
            [1] => V. Persie
        )

    [email_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mowen@owen.com
            [1] => vpersie@persie.com
        )

    [phone_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123-455-6555
            [1] => 222-111-1111
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

I want the data above will store to my current database format looks like below.

```
id  | fullname  |  email             | phone         | address           | zip    | uid
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | John Doe  | john@john.com      | 123-455-6444  | 23-10 My Address  | 12345  | 1
2   | M. Owen   | mowen@owen.com     |               |                   |        | 1
3   | V. Persie | vpersie@persie.com |               |                   |        | 1
```

I'm getting blur how to save the array to MySQL.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users SET fullname ='" . $fullname . "', email ='" . $email . "', phone='" . $phone . "', address ='" . $address . "', zip='" . $zip . "'";
$db->rq($query);
```

Let me know the clue.

Comment: First, please tell me that you are sanitising your data before inserting it. Second, what DB class are you using?  I don't recognise `->rq()`.

Comment: First, yes. Second I got the DB class from Google and it's run query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I assume that last column `uid` refers to id of user with all data inserted and is used to mark connection between first element and two others.

Secondly I do not know anything about php DB wrapper from Google (or can you provide any codename for this) so I assume that it is one of many db wrapper project hosted on `code.google.com`. Since I do'nt know which one is it , you'll have to look yourself for equivalent to [php function mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

And general algorithm to accomplish what you need:

1. Insert first row as in your example.
2. Get last insert id for this row.
3. Iterate through `$_POST['fullname_2']` to collect data for next query
4. Run it ;)

Example:

```
$lastId = $db->functionToGetLastId();
$valuesArray = array();
foreach($_POST['fullname_2'] as $key => $value){
    $fullname = sanitizeFunction($value);
    $email = sanitizeFunction($_POST['email_2'][$key]);
    $phone = sanitizeFunction($_POST['phone_2'][$key]);
    $valuesArray[] = "('{$fullname}','{$email}','{$phone}',{$lastId})";
}
$secondQuery = "INSERT INTO users (fullname,email,phone,uid) VALUES " . implode(',',$valuesArray);
$db->rq($secondQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. Take a look at simple [SQL INSERT syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).
3. Read about [escaping special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) in PHP MySQL API.
4. Read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Modify this code to fit your needs:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (FieldName1, FieldName2, ...) VALUES ('%s', '%s', ...)", mysql_real_escape_string($value1), mysql_real_escape_string($value2), ...);
```

Good luck!

Comment: 4. and read about DB normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @pleasedontbelong: added it as p. 4 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared queries instead of insert query 'as-is'
Something like this

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$conn = new PDO(...); //params of connection
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
   INSERT INTO users
   (fullname, phone)
   VALUES
   (?, ?)'
);
$stmt->execute(array(
     $fullname,
     $phone
));
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution. But why is it the best? And best for what? If I want to achieve a better performance I would stick to native API, for example. Plus, parametrized statements could be less efficient in case with MySQL, because MySQL itself doesn't support them and does not support precompiled statements (or does it? it's been a long time since I looked at it). So.. you know what I am saying.. more details :)

Comment: Ok, maybe "best" was too subjectively. However, if you want to use native API, you can try MySQLi driver, which also supports prepared statements almost same way as PDO. MySQL supports prepared statements well, as I know, and it helps to achive more perfomance, if you need to do same queries several times. Based on my post: $stmt->execute(array('John', '444')); $stmt->execute(array('Bill', '777')). As I know it should be faster than traditional mysql_query. Also prepared statements are more convinient, because, in general, you don't need to do sanitization of parameters before insertion.